# Problem with 'event_wait' in python3-libgpiod

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gpio, libgpiod

I am working with a Debian 11 (bullseye) based system on a aarch64 chip. The affected libraries are:

libgpiod2 1.6.2-1

python3-libgpiod 1.6.2-1

The Problem occurs in the following example:

```
import gpiod

GPIO_CHIP = "/dev/gpiochip0"
INPUT = 26

def main():
    chip = gpiod.Chip(GPIO_CHIP)
    line = chip.get_line(INPUT)
    line.request(consumer="GPOUT", type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_IN, flags=gpiod.LINE_REQ_FLAG_BIAS_PULL_UP)
    while True:
        if line.event_wait(600):
            event = line.event_read()
            print(event)

main()
```

The problem is that the method `event_wait` from the class `gpiod.Line` immediately with a `True` returns and the call of `event_read` then leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tegeth1/./IO_test_event.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tegeth1/./IO_test_event.py", line 15, in main
    event = line.event_read()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

because there is no event in the event-queue.

This behaviour does not occur if I just use:

```
$ gpiomon 0 26
```

on the command line.
Even this other python example, works as expected:

```
import gpiod
import select

GPIO_CHIP = "/dev/gpiochip0"
INPUT = 26

def main():
    chip = gpiod.Chip(GPIO_CHIP)
    line = chip.get_line(INPUT)
    line.request(consumer="GPOUT", type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_EV_BOTH_EDGES, flags=gpiod.LINE_REQ_FLAG_BIAS_PULL_UP)
    fd = line.event_get_fd()
    poll = select.poll()
    poll.register(fd)
    while True:
        poll.poll(None)
        event = line.event_read()
        print(event)

main()
```

I have already tried different biases and executed the script also on a Raspberry Pi (same chip architecture, comparable OS) with the same result. What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Many thanks and best regards,

Cone

Edit: If you ask, why I am not simply using the second solution, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677680/monitor-a-file-descriptor-in-background-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the second Python example, to receive event the line must be requested with type being one of the `LINE_REQ_EV_` types, such as `LINE_REQ_EV_BOTH_EDGES`.

What you do in your first example is request it as a plain input line, with type `LINE_REQ_DIR_IN`, which does not support interrupts or generate edge events.  Instead it returns errors when you try to use it in a way that you did not request it for.

Comment: Thanks, LINE_REQ_EV_BOTH_EDGES, does the trick for me!

Comment: Hi Kent, I am facing issue in gpiomon, I want to monitor a gpio pin using gpiomon so when I do gpiomon 0 5 it stays there and does not show any event even though the gpio pin is being driven high-low for 1 sec atleast. On the other side when I use gpioget as gpioget 0 5, I can see the appropriate value in result. Can you suggest what can be wrong with this behaviour of gpiomon? Thanks

Comment: @Dixit - not the best forum for debugging this.  gpiomon detects edges, so is your line being pulled both ways?  You don't mention your hardware - some hardware does not support edge detection.

Comment: @KentGibson Sorry for not using standard way of connecting with you, I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77192251/gpiomon-does-not-show-any-events-for-gpio que. The platform is exynos. Is there any way I can confirm whether it supports edge detection or not?