# gpiomon does not show any events for GPIO

Tags: linux, interrupt, gpio, libgpiod

I am trying to monitor a GPIO pin using `libgpiod` tools. The pinctrl has configured the pin as GPIO `ACTIVE_LOW PULL-DOWN`. Now when I read the pin using `gpioget 0 5`, I see the correct value getting retreived. So I expect the `gpiomon` to work the same way, i.e. whenever there is change in value (or rising-edge / falling-edge), the `gpiomon 0 5` should show those events. But it does not, instead it shows nothing. Even when I read GPIO value using sysfs (export GPIO pin and read its value) it shows correct value.

When I run `gpiomon` with `strace`, I can see the timeout being reached and it keeps polling the GPIO pin.

```c
mmap(0x6f6040b000, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x6f6040b000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x6f6040b000, 262144, "scudo:primary") = 0
ioctl(3, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, 0x7fc77d6ba0) = 0
mmap(0x702040e000, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x702040e000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x702040e000, 262144, "scudo:primary") = 0
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0xb4, 0x5, 0x100), 0x7fc77d6ab0) = 0
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0xb4, 0x7, 0x250), 0x7fc77d6990) = 0
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0xb4, 0x5, 0x100), 0x7fc77d6850) = 0
ppoll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, {tv_sec=10, tv_nsec=0}, NULL, 8) = 0 (Timeout)
ppoll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, {tv_sec=10, tv_nsec=0}, NULL, 8) = 0 (Timeout)
```

What I wanted to understand is:

1. How does `gpiomon` monitor events? Polling or interrupt? If it's interrupt based, how does `gpiomon` get to know which interrupt line is there for this GPIO?
2. Is there any dependency on pinctrl? Like do I need to configure the pin something like external interrupt to make it work with `gpiomon`?

[Edit 1]
output of the gpiodetect and gpioinfo:
[image]

Comment: You can download libgpiod sources and see how gpiomon works.

Comment: ```gpiomon``` is interrupt driven, not polled. It uses the kernel GPIO uAPI ioctls to request the line and then reads the events from the line request fd using poll().  The kernel does all the interrupt handling, and makes the edge events available via the fd.  The IRQ is provided by the underlying device driver, and that depends on your hardware - which you haven't specified.  The output from ``gpiodetect``` would help here.  If edge detection isn't supported, and the driver isn't buggy, then ```gpiomon``` should fail to request the line.

Comment: @KentGibson I kind'a understood few things, thanks. I have updated the Que with `gpiodetect` and `gpioinfo` output for your reference. We are interested in `gpa0 pin 5`
Please have a look and let me know if that information helps you understand something.

Comment: Which SoC are you using? I'm guessing you are using the pinctrl-exynos-arm64.c driver, but it is really necessary to know what hardware you have and what kernel version you are running, as the mainline driver doesn't appear to have any devices that match that set of gpiochips.

Comment: @KentGibson Its Exynos A920.

Comment: @KentGibson Kernel v5.15.

Comment: Got a reference to a datasheet for the A920?  And is that the mainline kernel or a fork?  Oh, I'm not familiar with with the SoC or driver, so not sure how much help I can be.

Comment: How do you setup sysfs for the working case? And please convert the picture into the text.